Where did my edit go? All history of the edit seems to have disappeared
On this Question:
Cool White LED bulbs: Are they "full-spectrum"?
The last comment pointed out a flaw in my answer that I then edited my answer for. I then posted a comment to let the commentor know I'd fixed it. Initially, my edit happened and as "evidence" of that, someone upvoted my comment who I assume was the last commenter.
When I came back a few days later, a number of problems seem to have happened.

The edit disappeared without a trace.
The timeline never shows it.
The comments remained, but the timeline doesn't even record my last comment.

What happened?
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/125500/timeline?filter=NoVoteDetail

We are sorry you are experiencing issues with the site. If the edit was not recorded it's likely that it was a communication error. If we don't have any information on the timeline we can't really debug the problem. If you could try and reproduce the error that would be helpful.

Yeah, I would guess that there's a bug in database/server syncing, but I'm sure that's not easy to track down unless I can reliably reproduce the issue.

Could be a local browser issue

Really? Even when someone upvoted my comment indicating they had seen a change?

Probably not if someone else saw the change, could be a database problem. I don't have access to that so I can't help there. I can help with issue that are reproducible.
